# Division with remainder in $K[X]$ where $K$ is an arbitrary field.

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory

I have some struggles with using Division with remainder in an arbitary poylnomial ring $K[X]$ where $K$ is some field.

For instance consider the polynomial $f=X^{3}-X-1\in k[X]$, and consider the polynomial $g=3X^{2}-1\in K[X]$. I want to apply Division with remainder to these two polynomials. By this Theorem we have unique $q,r\in K[X]$ such that $f=qg+r$ and either $\deg(r)<\deg(g)$ or $r=0$.

The intuitive way would be to say that

$X^{3}-X-1=\frac{1}{3}X(3X^2-1)-\frac{2}{3}X-1$,

and thus $q=\frac{1}{3}X$ and $r=-\frac{2}{3}X-1$. But do we indeed have $q,r\in K[X]$? What does the $\frac{1}{3}$ mean here? I know that for integers $n$ we actually have in general fields $K$ that $n$ is just defined as adding $1$ $n$-times. So could we make sense of $\frac{1}{3}$ as the inverse of $(1+1+1)$? In advance thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, since $K$ is a field, $3$ has an inverse, which you can write as $\frac{1}{3}$. If $K$ is of chacteristic $0$, then $K$ contains a copy of $\mathbb Q$ and this is just the rational number $\frac{1}{3}$. If $K$ has positive characteristic, then it contains a copy of ${\mathbb F}_p$ for some prime $p$, and the inverse of $3$ is in this field; it is then more customary to write $3^{-1}$ instead of $\frac13$. (And, for completeness sake, if $p = 3$, then $3 = 0$ and it doesn't have an inverse, but then also your polynomial $g$ is really just $-1$).